# Is it correct to say "I untwisted the rope that was made by twisting thinner strings together"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

A rope was made by twisting thinner strings together. You used your fingers to make strings of the rope untwisted from each other.

It seems like we have this structure in the dictionary "**twist something (into something)**".

Would you say "**I twisted thin strings into a rope then I disentwined the rope**" or "**I twisted thin strings into a rope then I untwisted the rope**" in everyday conversation?

[image]

Comment: Asking "is this correct" is off-topic on this site. Can you show some research - why do you think it might be wrong? I know you quoted a dictionary, but your example follows the dictionary structure so I don't understand why you think it might not be right?

Comment: Ropes are, by definition, made by twisting smaller cords together. If the ends are coming apart they are _fraying_. If you are doing this on purpose you are _unpicking_ the rope.